# TextBox validation error with focus and backColor change

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I have a simple calculator application in which I used two `textBox` , the first is for entering first value and second is for second value the issue is with the code which will turn the focus on an empty `textBox` also will change its `backColor`.
code are required in loop using `foreach` in case of having multiple `textBox` on a form.

The code for empty textbox error is written in the result click button as:

```
if(textBox1.Text=="" || textBox2.Text=="")
{
 MessageBox.Show("Error","Error");
 //Required codes !!
}
```

Comment: The problem is how to make a focus and backColor change on empty textBox not only in this code but when having multiple textBox

Comment: I see... In that case then you may want to check if your textbox is empty by using `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` on your `textBox.Text`. Also, you may want to refer the `textBox_TextChanged` events in your multiple TextBoxes to a single event handler. Then, you assign the backColor of whoever is the `sender` to the color you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

probably you are looking for this:

```
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox1.Text.Trim()))
{
   textBox1.Focus();
   textBox1.BackColor = Color.Red;
} 
else if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox2.Text.Trim()))
{
   textBox2.Focus();
   textBox2.BackColor = Color.Red;
}
```

and this Will Help you **validate** all the `TexBox` Controls:

```
foreach (Control control in this.Controls)
{
    if (control.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
    {
         TextBox textBox = (TextBox)control;
         if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox.Text.Trim()))
         {
             textBox.Focus();
             textBox.BackColor = Color.Red;
         }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:** I modified `==` comparison with string method `IsNullOrEmpty()` plus I called an extra method `Trim()` that will basically remove all the leading and trailing whitespaces from input. So, if the user has inputted only blank spaces, it will remove them then see if it becomes empty or not.

Comment: This will help me , but how to make this code run for multiple textBox not just this two textBox , using foreach

Comment: you can use your forms control collection, iterate through it, check if the control is a TextBox, and also check if the name of the TextBox matches a pattern for the Textboxes to check ... or you can use the Tag element of the TextBox to set up Group of validations

Comment: Recheck my Answer, I've Edited it

Answer (score 0):

As written in my comment, iterating the form control collection:

Sample 1:

```
 foreach (Control co in this.Controls)
 {
     if (co.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
     {
          MessageBox.Show(co.Name);
     }
 }
```

Sample 2:

```
foreach (Control co in this.Controls)
{
    if (co.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
    {
        TextBox tb = co as TextBox;
        MessageBox.Show(co.Name + "/" + co.Tag);
    }
}
```

Sample 3:

```
foreach (Control co in this.Controls)
{
    TextBox tb = co as TextBox;
    if (tb != null)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace((string)tb.Tag))
        {
            MessageBox.Show(co.Name + "/" + co.Tag);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(co.Name + " ... without tag");
        }
    }
}
```